# How to filter objects at django based on related field?

Tags: django, django-database, django-request

I have models:

- Product
- Store
- ProductStore (additional table with foreign keys to `Store` and `Product`, also Boolean 'enabled', and stock(integer) )

The questions:

How can I filter `Product`s which has `Enabled=True` for current `store__id` (from request)? 
Also, how can I add an additional field for every objects with stock at current store?

UPDATED:

```
class Product(models.Model): 
   pass 
class Store(models.Model):
   pass
class ProductStoreInfo(models.Model):
   enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='stock_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name="stock", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   stock = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Stock'), blank=True, null=True, default=0, max_length=255)
   price = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Price'), blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code of these models.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem Updated, I guess need to use Q expressions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter this with:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    stock_info__enabled=True
    stock_info__store_id=my_store_id
)
```

This will thus return a `QuerySet` that contains only `Product`s for which there is a *related* `ProductStoreInfo` for which `enabled` is `True` and the `store_id` is the `my_store_id` (to be replaced with an expression that results in such id).

We can also annotate our queryset with the stock data, like:

```
from django.db.models import F, Min

Product.objects.filter(
    stock_info__enabled=True
    stock_info__store_id=my_store_id
).annotate(
    stock=Min(F('store_info__stock'))
)
```

Here the `Product` objects from the queryset will have an extra attribute `.stock` that contains the `stock` column of the relevant `ProductStore` object (that satisfies the filtering).

Comment: AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'lookup' (Django version 1.7.11)

Comment: @petriichuk: you should really upgrade Django, Django-1.7.11 is not supported anymore since december, 2015 (!) https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ and at that moment the ORM was indeed not "powerful enough" to do this.

Comment: upgraded, but does not filter... just return zero objects. Just to clarify, there are row for every store-product relation

Comment: getting error at annotate stage...the problem is that there are many related object...i need to get one by two parameters (product, store)..

Comment: You should get the one of the given `store_id`, if there are multiple `stock_info`s for that given `Product` and `Store`, then you get all of these in *separate* `Product` objects.

Comment: getting an error:  (1055, &quot;Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column &#39;vw_dev_stock.products_productstoreinfo.stock&#39; which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by&quot;)

Comment: @petriichuk: what if you add `Min(..)` over it?

Comment: Min, Sum etc works...but I need just annotate the data (stock field) from ProductStoreInfo object which relates to current product and store_id Im getting from request...  There are many store_info objects related to every Product.. but I need exactly one, with store_id, which I get from request

Comment: @petriichuk: yes, this should do. The problem is that SQL does not allow to mention fields, since it assumes there can be multiple. We thus need an aggregate, and `MIN(..)` will give the lexicographically minimum of all `stock_info` for *that* product, and *that* stock. Here there is one, but the SQL "concept" layer does not know that.